# Can an HTML <select> element "value" attribute be an object?

Tags: reactjs, forms

I'm building a React application in which it would be convenient to send an object as data from a form. The value of my select element begins as an object, but it is turned into a string, "[object OBJECT]", when I submit it. Is what I'm trying to do possible? Are HTML form values always strings? Or am I maybe doing something wrong?
Here's what I'm trying...

```
                  <form onSubmit={props.handleAssignment}>
                    <div className="form-group">
                      <label htmlFor="assignSelect">Assign Support</label>
                      <select
                        className="form-control"
                        id="assignSelect"
                        defaultValue={"DEFAULT"}
                        onChange={e => props.setAssignment(e.target.value)}
                        required
                      >
                        <option value="DEFAULT" disabled>
                          Select Technician
                        </option>
                        {props.support.map(s => (
                          <option value={s} key={s.username}>
                            {s.username}
                          </option>
                        ))}
                      </select>
                      <button className="btn btn-secondary mt-2">Assign</button>
                    </div>
                  </form>
```

`props.support` is an array of objects, (members of support personnel), each with username and email attributes. I'm able to access the username attribute to populate the option fields, so I'm confident that "s" is an object at this point in the code.

Here is the hook that handles "assignment" state:

```
let [assignment, setAssignment] = useState({});
```

I put a `console.log(typeof assignment)` statement in a useEffect function that updates on `assignment` state change. Before any selection is made, it returns "object", but as soon as I select an option and `assignment` is updated, it returns "string".
This is a help desk/issue tracker application, and the end goal is to send the support member object to the back end server to update a support ticket in the database, (using the username attribute,) and send an email, (using the email attribute), to the support member to let them know they have a new assignment.
Thanks in advance for any insight!